# Remove file from *.jar, using script

Tags: java, bash, cmd, ear

I have next package structure

webService.ear -- dependency.jar -- some.class

Can I remove **some.class** from .ear using cmd script and bash script?

**Solution:**
I wrote cmd script for this:

```
call unzip target\webService.ear -d tmp
call zip -d target\tmp\dependency.jar \com\mypackage1\MyClass1.class
call zip -d target\tmp\dependency.jar \com\mypackage2\MyClass2.class 
call jar cvfM target\webService.ear -C tmp .
```

May be, this will be helpful for someone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no option to the `jar` command to remove entries.

However, the jar format is processable with zip tools, so you should be able to use a command-line zip (GNU zip, for instance) to remove members.